# Cakephp paginate data from model

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

Retrieving remote data. (but thats not the problem)

*Model:*

```
Class myModel {

 public function list_posts($cat){
    $posts= json_decode($this->http->get($this->base_url."/myPath/".$cat), true);
    return $posts;
 }
}
```

*Controller:*

```
Class myController {

   public function index() {
   $cat = 'mycat'
   $posts= $this->myModel->list_posts($cat);
   $this->set('works',$obras);
   }
}
```

How can I use `$this->paginate()` method over data that had been retrieved?

Comment: you can't. Paginate is used to directly build the query to interrogate the database prior to ratrieve the data and not after. Instead it seems that you are getting your data through an http request. We don't know what you are doing in your /myPath/$cat url but if you are using cakePHP there too, then that is the page you have to modify in order to get your data aklready paginated. Otherwise you have to create your paginator component

Comment: you can experiment with e.g. [the array datasource](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/master/Model/Datasource/ArraySource.php) or simply recognise that paginating existing data isn't pagination - it's array-chunking. Why are you apparently issuing  http requests to your own application ?!?